# Swift get from string array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a string array and I want to get string from number.

Example:

```
let dateArray = ["01.09.2018 05:24:00", 
    "02.09.2018 05:29:00", "03.09.2018 05:34:00", 
    "04.09.2018 05:39:00", "05.09.2018 05:44:00", 
    "06.09.2018 05:49:00", "07.09.2018 05:54:02", 
    "08.09.2018 05:59:00", "09.09.2018 06:04:00", 
    "10.09.2018 06:09:00", "11.09.2018 06:14:00", 
    "12.09.2018 06:19:18", "13.09.2018 06:24:00", 
    "14.09.2018 06:29:00", "15.09.2018 06:34:00", 
    "16.09.2018 06:39:00", "17.09.2018 06:44:00", 
    "18.09.2018 06:49:00", "19.09.2018 06:54:00", 
    "20.09.2018 06:59:00", "21.09.2018 07:04:00"]
```

I need to get 5th position from array  // the answer must be - "05.09.2018 05:44:00"

Or need 10th position // the answer must be - "10.09.2018 06:09:00"

How can I do this?

Comment: index = position - 1

Comment: getting an element from array isn't that hard it's prior to Basics

Comment: You may wish to read the section on [Arrays](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID107) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `dateArray[4]`, seems straightforward to me. Array indexes are 0-based in Swift.

You could declare a function like so:

```
extension Array {
    func getElement(position: Int) -> Element {
        guard self.count > 0, position > 0, position <= self.count else {
            fatalError("Error")
        }
        return self[position - 1]
    }
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
dateArray.getElement(position: 5)    //"05.09.2018 05:44:00"
dateArray.getElement(position: 10)   //"10.09.2018 06:09:00"
```